# Is it safe to mount a Linux partition mounted using WSL2 in hibernated Windows 11?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hibernate, ext4

WSL2 comes with support for mounting Linux partitions from non-removable drives in updated Windows 10 and Windows 11. When creating an ext2/3/4 partition, for example, on an internal drive, this partition is automatically visible in File Explorer and mounted after booting into Windows. Is it okay to hibernate such Windows machine or to leave Fast Startup enabled and then "shut down" Windows and to write to that Linux partition after booting into Linux while not having Windows properly shut down? Or is disabling hibernation and Fast Startup in Windows the only option how to make dualboot safe with WSL2 if one wants to keep writing to the shared partition enabled from both operating systems? Is there an alternative, e.g., setting a scheduled task in Windows, triggered right before fast shut down and hibernation? I am aware that mounting Windows-native NTFS file systems in Linux while the Windows OS is hibernated is not safe.
Thank you.

Comment: I would go with *generally regarded as safe* because Windows shouldn't be using ext2/3/4 partitions for hibernation or Fast Startup purposes ... Also AFAIK even not all NTFS partitions on windows aside from the main system partition are equally affected/contaminated/made dirty by Fast Startup upon incomplete shutdown ,,, @NotTheDr01ds :-)